# Como integrar um App a uma WebService ASP.NET (ASMX) via Xamarin?

Tags: asp.net, web-service, xamarin, app

Bom dia, eu tenho um servidor sql criado com uma web service asp.net, mas eu queria saber como eu faço para que eu integre os dados do servidor criando um app para que o leia utilizando a requisição GET.

Desde já, agradeço a atenção

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente, você utilizaria como em qualquer aplicação C#.

Porem segue um exemplo mais especifico da própria xamarin : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/asmx/